# Magento 2 Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString()

Tags: magento2, admin, category, edit

Please check below error:

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array in
>   /vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php
>   on line 0

I can  see the above error when I go to the admin > Catalog > Manage Category
and choose any category to edit.

Please help me if you face any kind of this issues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you make any changes in core modules.?

Comment: In your custom construct argument are different so this issue occur.

First check after removing generated folder.
if it will not work check which module's code affected it

Comment: @AskBytes No, I didn't make any changes in core files

Comment: Hi, @RutveeSojitra I have setup 2 environment 1st for production and 2nd is the clone of production as staging. That same error I didn't get on staging and I got the above error on production. I also tried with your answers but it's not working can you please help me to fix that error with your great suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RutveeSojitra see I got the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed the above mention issue which I mention in my question.

I got the error is actually coming from the Core files.

> Just go to the file using below path:
>   **> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php**

Should use $attributeCode as lines 495 & 496 rather than hardcoded ['image']

Like below code

```
$categoryData[$attributeCode][0]['size'] = isset($stat) ? $stat['size'] : 0;
$categoryData[$attributeCode][0]['type'] = $mime;
```

I hope its working for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this in your di.xml in  tag

```
type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult"
```

Your di.xml will be like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">you_table_name</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Region</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="your_table_name" xsi:type="string">vendor\module\Model\ResourceModel\Region\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```